# Center Div Horizontally With Scroll CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image]

I want to center the divs horizontally with an option to scroll using css. How can I achieve that? I saw a solution using the margin auto and max width but the div will be cut on the edges due to the maximum width which is 30rem.so I do not want that. What I want is to scroll only if the contents have no space left.

Please notice how the edges are cut. Yes it is scrollable but since there is space available I want to use it.

```css
.az-chips-btns-parent {
  overflow  : auto;
  margin    : auto;
  max-width : 30rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">

<div class="az-chips-btns-parent">
  <div class="az-chips-btns">
    <div class="az-save-filters-parent" style="margin-top: 1.5px;"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn p-0 rounded-circle az-save-filters-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
        <i class="fa fa-star az-save-filters" style="font-size: 15px;"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn az-country-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
      <div>Country</div>
      <div class="az-country-selected-chip az-selected-chip text-danger">3 selected</div>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn az-brand-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
      <div>Brand</div>
      <div class="az-brand-selected-chip az-selected-chip text-danger"></div>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn az-location-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
      <div>Location</div>
      <div class="az-location-selected-chip az-selected-chip text-danger"></div>
    </button>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn az-store-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
      <div>Store</div>
      <div class="az-store-selected-chip az-selected-chip text-danger"></div>
    </button>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn az-section-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
      <div>Section</div>
      <div class="az-section-selected-chip az-selected-chip text-danger"></div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: obviously you are using a CSS framework. there is arguably a class provided to get what you are looking for

Comment: What does »but the div will be cut« mean? What is it that you don't want?

Comment: Could you maybe add a picture or illustration to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: what do you mean? it's currently centered, the div.as-chips-btns-parent is centered!

Comment: I have given a solution. Do you need such a result?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov it is useless, once again we are dealing with a PO asking a question and then immediately disappears, the answers do not interest him. I don't count them anymore, but there must be thousands here!

Comment: @MisterJojo, Yes, I also met such a problem with the OP. But I will hope that the OP of this question will come back soon and give his comment.

Comment: Thank u guys for your time to respond. When I continue working with it I'll post a picture currently I will edit the question to be more understandable

Comment: @Sam, check my new solution, pls.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov awesome it worked! I changed only the max-width to 100% to get what I needed. please explain

Comment: @Sam, I'm glad my solution helped. I have given a description for each rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexibility rules for button and parent elements can be used to accomplish your task.

For parent class `az-chips-btns`, you set basic flexibility rules, such as `display: flex` and `align-items: center` (horizontal alignment of elements within the parent), as well as a `gap: 10px` rule that sets the spacing between children.

For all first-level children, you set rule `flex: 1`, which allows you to accept the same width relative to each other within the parent.

```css
.az-chips-btns-parent {
  overflow  : auto;
  margin    : auto;
  max-width : 30rem;
}

.az-chips-btns {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.az-chips-btns > * {
  flex: 1;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">

<div class="az-chips-btns-parent">
    <div class="az-chips-btns">
        <div class="az-save-filters-parent" style="margin-top: 1.5px;"> 
            <button type="button" class="btn p-0 rounded-circle az-save-filters-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
                <i class="fa fa-star az-save-filters" style="font-size: 15px;"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn az-country-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
        <div>Country</div>
            <div class="az-country-selected-chip az-selected-chip text-danger">3 selected</div>
        </button>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn az-brand-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
          <div>Brand</div>
          <div class="az-brand-selected-chip az-selected-chip text-danger"></div>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn az-location-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
            <div>Location</div>
            <div class="az-location-selected-chip az-selected-chip text-danger"></div>
        </button>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn az-store-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
            <div>Store</div>
            <div class="az-store-selected-chip az-selected-chip text-danger"></div>
        </button>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn az-section-chip ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">
            <div>Section</div>
            <div class="az-section-selected-chip az-selected-chip text-danger"></div>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```